# How can i incorporate a load / save function into my game written in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-2.x

How can I incorporate saving and loading to a file in my game written in python 2.7.
The source code is available https://github.com/bob53124/Charlies-Adventure/blob/master/game.py here to view. If you have any idea please reply. BTW im writing it on a linux box

Answer (score 5):

You can serialize an object to the disk using the Pickle library.

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

When you restore the object you will get an exact replica in memory.

So you can just pickle up all your game state objects to save. To load just unpickle them in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give some examples, expanding on @user604653 answer...

```
import cPickle

gameData = {'level':1, 'score': 5000}

# save
fh = open("game.save", 'wb')
cPickle.dump(gameData, fh)
fh.close()

# load
fh = open("game.save", 'rb')
gameData2 = cPickle.load(fh)
fh.close()
```